# Hyperref ignoring \subsubsectionautorefname

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, cross-referencing

In my document I use `\autoref` to reference to a `\subsubsection` but instead of printing the `\subsubsectionautorefname` text (as expected) LaTeX prints the `\sectionautorefname` text. Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

\addto\extrasngerman{%
    \def\sectionautorefname{SECTION}%
    \def\subsectionautorefname{Sub-Abschnitt}%
    \def\subsubsectionautorefname{SubSub-Abschnitt}%
}

\newcommand*{\QuoteM}[1]{\frqq #1\flqq}

\newcommand*{\SeeS}[1]
{(siehe auch \autoref{#1} \QuoteM{\nameref{#1}} auf \autopageref{#1})}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter} \label{1}
\section{section} \label{2}
\subsection{subsection} \label{3}
\subsubsection{subsubsection} \label{4}

\section{section2}

\SeeS{1}\\
\SeeS{2}\\
\SeeS{3}\\
\SeeS{4}\\

\end{document}
```

As a result I would expect:

```
(siehe auch Kapitel 1 »chapter« auf Seite 1) 
(siehe auch SECTION 1.1 »section« auf Seite 1) 
(siehe auch Sub-Abschnitt 1.1.1 »subsection« auf Seite 1) 
(siehe auch SubSub-Abschnitt 1.1.1 »subsubsection« auf Seite 1)
```

But instead I got:

```
(siehe auch Kapitel 1 »chapter« auf Seite 1) 
(siehe auch SECTION 1.1 »section« auf Seite 1) 
(siehe auch Sub-Abschnitt 1.1.1 »subsection« auf Seite 1) 
(siehe auch SECTION 1.1.1 »subsubsection« auf Seite 1)
```

How do I change the existing into the expected behavior ?

Comment: 'Sub-Abschnitt'? Echt jetzt? ;-) ... and numbers as label names are weird and error-prone

Comment: It's just an example, in the real document I use proper names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the wrong auto ref name expansion in order to get the correct counter name is that `subsubsection` isn't numbered at all, so set the `secnumdepth` counter to `3` here.

`\autoref` uses the hyper anchor name stored with the `\newlabel` command in `.aux`. For an unnumbered `subsubsection`, `section*.X` is written to the file, where `X` is replaced by an integer number -- `\autoref` extracts  `section*` then and assumes that the `section` counter was involved.

From a viewpoint of German styling I would not write *Sub-Abschnitt* but *Unterabschnitt* rather. `\subsubsection` does not really have an appropriate translation into German.

Also don't use `\\` after the `\SeeS` macros. An empty line between each `\SeeS{...}` will also provide a line break.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}


\addto\extrasngerman{%
    \def\sectionautorefname{SECTION}%
    \def\subsectionautorefname{Sub-Abschnitt}%
    \def\subsubsectionautorefname{SubSub-Abschnitt}%
}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\newcommand*{\QuoteM}[1]{\frqq #1\flqq}

\newcommand*{\SeeS}[1]
{(siehe auch \autoref{#1} \QuoteM{\nameref{#1}} auf \autopageref{#1})}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter} \label{1}
\section{section} \label{2}
\subsection{subsection} \label{3}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}\label{4}

\section{section2}

\SeeS{1}

\SeeS{2}

\SeeS{3}

\SeeS{4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this one dose to trick, thanks. But (of course) now I have 4 digits numbering like "1.1.3.1 Anwendungsfall: Politik". Is there a way to only have 3 digits e.g. "1.1.3 Anwendungsfall: Politik" ?

Comment: @John.Doe_876: That's the usual way to count subsubsections.... `chapter.section.subsection.subsubsection`. You can strip the chapter number of course, but if there's another subsubsection `1.1.3` it is not clear to which chapter this number belongs